# track by does not work with order by in Angular 1.5 - Expected array but received

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-filter

After migration from Angular 1.4.11 to 1.5.8 I run into this error:

`Error: [orderBy:notarray] Expected array but received: 3455`

I've located it in this expression:

```
ng-options="profile.name for profile in vm.allProfiles track by profile.id | orderBy: 'name'"
```

but when changed to

```
ng-options="profile.name for profile in vm.allProfiles | orderBy: 'name'"
```

it works.

I didn't find any relation to breaking changes yet. Do you know what is going on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filters should be applied to the expression(here its an `Array`), before specifying a tracking expression. Because `orderBy` filter applies `array` not `track by`.

```
ng-options="profile.name for profile in vm.allProfiles | orderBy: 'name' track by profile.id"
```